# machine does not start -VBoxHardening.log - startup with exit code 1 (0x1) - (0x80004005)

Tags: virtualbox

```
The virtual machine 'chrome crx and sni' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
More details may be available in 'C:\Users\USR\VirtualBox VMs\chrome crx and sni\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.
```

---

```
Kod wyniku (RC): 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Komponent: 
MachineWrap
Interfejs: 
IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
```

VirtualBox freshly installed. I do not know if this matters, but on my computer I have the Python interpreter installed in versions 2.7.13 and 3.4.0 and Avast antivirus.

Where can I paste VBoxHardening.log?

```
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll (Input=CRYPTBASE.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000002a4c1c0:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts [calling]
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefcbe0000 'C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll'
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hFile=0000000000000528 pwszName=\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: Cached context 00000000008056a0
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hCatAdmin=00000000008056a0
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: cbHash=20 wszDigest=936D45CC7026757A151F62882B557DD75D5FCB21
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: WinVerifyTrust => 0x0; cat='C:\Windows\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\ntpe.cat'; file='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'
810.300: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile -> 0 (org 22900)
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #0 'msvcrt.dll'.
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #6 'user32.dll'.
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #7 'gdi32.dll'.
810.300: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll) WinVerifyTrust
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'gdi32.dll'...
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'gdi32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'user32.dll'...
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'user32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\user32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'msvcrt.dll'...
810.300: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'msvcrt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000003320710:C:\Windows\system32;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts [calling]
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007fefb1d0000 LB 0x00056000 C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll [fFlags=0x0]
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefb1d0000 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll'
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000003320710:C:\Windows\system32;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts [calling]
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefb1d0000 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll'
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000003320710:C:\Windows\system32;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts [calling]
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefb1d0000 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll'
810.300: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000003320710:C:\Windows\system32;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts [calling]
810.300: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefb1d0000 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll'
ad0.14d8: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[2]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 1170 ms, the end);
318.d10: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 1775 ms, the end);
```

[VBoxHardening.log](https://pastebin.com/tknNLCW9) << full code on pastebin

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to insert the log? What does that mean? Are you asking if you can paste the log here for us to read?

Comment: I mean on what page I can paste the log.

Comment: If it's not ridiculously long you can paste it into the body of your post.

Comment: I've tried before. It has 2435 lines.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that does qualify as ridiculously long. But probably it's not necessary to include it all, right? I imagine only the bottom portion contains the relevant recent errors. Just include that if possible.

Comment: Otherwise pastebin is an option, but we generally like to keep all the relevant info on this site itself for searchability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

The last entries in your log points to the `uxtheme.dll` file, one of the vital system files in Windows, which implies that you have a hacked version of it.  <sup>[(1)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/search.php?keywords=uxtheme&t=82106&sf=msgonly)</sup>

As far as I know, there are two ways to get around this issue:

## Solution A  <sub>/ Ideal (...and arguably practical)</sub>

You should replace it with an original copy of it (from an *unmodified* or *non-hacked* Windows installation). <sup>[(1)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/search.php?keywords=uxtheme&t=82106&sf=msgonly)</sup>

## Solution B  <sub>/ Fastest workaround</sub>

There are other ways to start a virtual machine in VirtualBox.

Use **Headless start**, it worked for me.

---

> Source (1): https://forums.virtualbox.org/search.php?keywords=uxtheme&t=82106&sf=msgonly